# Which Integration Style do Webservices apply to?

Tags: web-services, integration, messaging

I am currently thinking about Integration styles. Following Gregor Hohpe and Bobby Woolf (http://eaipatterns.com/) the basic integration styles are

- File Transfer
- Shared Database
- Remote Procedure Invocation
- Messaging

which I understand. But which of these styles do WebServices generally apply to? 
Would REST for example be a File Transfer style as it is be used to transfer resources over HTTP? 
SOAP RPC applies to Remote Procedure Invocation I guess, but what about non-RPC SOAP?
WebServices could even apply to Messaging, i.e. SOAP over MQ, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST calls are fundamentally Remote Procedure Invocations, as they are a lightweight way to perform method calls.

Messaging such as SOAP over MQ means looking at REST as a transport, the same way that a binary protocol over TCP is a transport.

File Transfers over HTTP, where the files are ordinary files (not XML or JSON) are no considered to be REST calls.